# Getting an array element

Tags: php

This problem is old and basic but I can't figure out a better way to get it right without looping through the whole array

```
$a=array(
'a'=>array
    (
      'x'=>'something',
      'y'=>'somethingelse',
      'z'=>'another thing'
    );
);
```

I would like to get the value of 'y' key.

I try this

```
foreach($a as $k=>$v)
{
  foreach($v as $vv)
  {
    return $v['y']
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks for your posts. How stupid I am :shy:

Comment: I would think this would be as simple as using `$a['a']['y']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $a['a']['y'];
```

This is me adding characters to reach the 30 char minimum.

Comment: I thought about answering this way (hence my comment above), but it seemed to me there must be more to this problem than meets the eye.

Comment: Haha I know, sometimes when the answer is so basic I feel bad posting an answer as it feels like cheap upvote trawling. I usually opt for the comment route myself.